# Programming a sandbox environment in rebol a bit like spoon.net

Tags: rebol

http://spoon.net let's you execute desktop application by downloading them from the web. When you quit it restores the system.

On http://askpoweruser.com I'd like to do the same thing. My idea would be to persist the whole system hierarchy on disk and then restore it at the end of execution.

Is a single line of code would be enough (seems like too easy for such complex feature that's why I doubt :)):

```
save %system.txt system
```

what is serialize refinement ? would it be usefull in that case ?

to restore system would I then just do

```
load %system.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my object:

```
>> o: context [b: "b" f: does [do make function! [] [print ["a"]]] oo: context [a: 1]]
>> ?? o
== o: make object! [
    b: "b"
    f: func [][do make function! [] [print ["a"]]]
    oo: make object! [
        a: 1
    ]
]
```

change something in function f:

```
>> o/oo/a: 2
>> append second last second first next next next third :o "b"
>> o/f
== a b
>> save/all %t.r :o
>> p: load %t.r
>> ?? p
== p: make object! [
    b: "b"
    f: func [][do make function! [] [print ["a" "b"]]] ;<----
    oo: make object! [
        a: 2              ;<------
    ]
]
>> p/f
== a b ;<----
```

it looks everything is ok. But of course this is just a single test.

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently save the entire Rebol image like this.  You can serialize Rebol values by using 'mold/all and save values by using 'save.  But AFAIK the serialization doesn't properly save functions inside objects.

Comment: still can I do it if I can create a function to also save the functions ?

Comment: @Graham: I tried saving & loading several different functions-inside-an-object and it worked. Could you give an example that doesn't work?

Comment: I can't find an example now ... but I did have a problem with serializing and restoring some Rebol objects last year, and I was told it was a Rebol bug.

Comment: @endo64 @grahm can you post your code that works and that doesn't ?

Comment: I made an example with some nested objects, functions which has local block variables etc. and it worked all of them, I'll write it as an answer for formatting issues.

Comment: There are 2 major problem about this: one is port states, network ports etc. cannot be saved and loaded easily. and the second is circular references. For ex. you cannot save & load this object: o: context [a: self] ; try to save/all and open the file you will see "#[object! [b: #[object! [...]]]" it gives error when you load it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like CryoPID:

http://cryopid.berlios.de/

That would work at the process level, and you could use it for things besides Rebol.  But it would be OS-specific.

Comment: I don't need to go as far but why not thanks for this amazing findings I didn't know it even exists :)